# Changing the background color of winform using ColorDialog

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am trying to change the background color of the winform.For this i am using `ColorDialog` in the constructor of the winform.The problem that i am facing is that i am not able to set the color in RGB format.
Here is the code..

```
    public ChangeAsPerApp()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ColorDialog cddialog = new ColorDialog();

        if (true) {

           //How to set the color here either in RGB or 
           //Some predefined colors or others options available here

          //I am trying like this but not able to set color
           this.BackColor = cddialog.Color;

        }
    }
```

Please help me ...Please help me to set color in RGB format.
Thanks

Comment: `ColorDialog.CustomColors` property is what you're after?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel How can i set RGB color into it..?

Comment: How you have the color data? Where did you get it from?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I have it in my database and user can choose any specific and that value can be used here.So if i have the color codes how can i set it here?

Comment: What is the data type of the value you have? Post some sample value you have and also its datatype.

Comment: I think [`Color.FromArgb()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.drawing.color.fromargb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method is what you're looking for.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel The values are in `string`

Comment: String as what? "ABC" also string, "123" also string. "Orange" also a string. What is the representation of color you have.

Comment: @ShivamShlom Posted it as an answer, check it if you can :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Color.FromArgb()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.drawing.color.fromargb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public ChangeAsPerApp()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    if (true) {
       Color Warn1Color = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0);//default colour
       this.BackColor = Warn1Color;;

    }
}
```

Source: [C# - using ColorDialog across forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7107650/c-sharp-using-colordialog-across-forms)